# Error using `NSDictionary` in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm very new to swift and im trying to display a collection of images in collection view

I get an error with this code

```
let asset: PHAsset = self.photoAsset[indexPath.item] as PHAsset
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .ScaleAspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {
            (result: UIImage!, info: NSDictionary!)in cell.setThumbnailImage(result)

        })
```

`'[NSObject : AnyObject]' is not identical to 'NSDictionary'` is the error and I have no idea how to fix it?

Comment: You don't have to specify `NSDictionary` explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help says

```
func requestImageForAsset(_ asset: PHAsset!,
           targetSize targetSize: CGSize,
          contentMode contentMode: PHImageContentMode,
              options options: PHImageRequestOptions!,
        resultHandler resultHandler: ((UIImage!,
            [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) -> PHImageRequestID
```

and you supply

```
info: NSDictionary!
```

Change it so you supply

```
info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!
```